# Libgdx - Using TextureAtlas with Skin. Memory Consideration?

Tags: memory, libgdx, assets, texture-atlas

I am using `TextureAtlas` to load my assets for a game in Libgdx. I know that TextureAtlas's method `findRegion` is expensive, memory wise, so it should be loaded once and stored.

I was just going through the `Skin` class where I encountered this example:

```
TextureAtlas atlas = ...
Skin skin = new Skin();
skin.addRegions(atlas);
...
TextureRegion hero = skin.get("hero", TextureRegion.class);
```

This means that I can get my textures using Skin as well. My question is, how does the Skin class loads these assets. Does it loads everything upon `skin.addRegions(atlas);`? Or does the  `skin.get("hero", TextureRegion.class);`loads it from the TextureAtlas on every call, making it as expensive as the `atlas.findRegion("hero")` call?

I am looking to load all my assets from TextureAtlas at the start of game. So I was thinking that I could do a simple load in skin and then use my assets from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from the source that the regions added to the `Skin` are stored in an `Array` and found via string comparison in 0.9.8 just as they are in the `TextureAtlas`. The lookup times will be similar.

Comment: So, if I want to load all my assets from the TextureAtlas at start, I have no other option than to load everything by name one by one?